# Thingsboard fails to start after upgrade to 2.3.0

Tags: upgrade, thingsboard

After upgrading Thingsboard from 2.2.0 to 2.3.0, the service is not starting, 
the below error message is shown in the log.

> 2019-02-14 10:16:23,996 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication -
>   Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'baseRuleChainTransactionService': Injection
>   of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'actors.rule.transaction.queue_size' in string value
>   "${actors.rule.transaction.queue_size}"   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
>     at
>   org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardServerApplication.main(ThingsboardServerApplication.java:38)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:521)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'actors.rule.transaction.queue_size' in string value
>   "${actors.rule.transaction.queue_size}"   at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:219)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:813)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
>     ... 25 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the [thingsboard.yml](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/v2.3/application/src/main/resources/thingsboard.yml#L218) configuration file to add **actors.rule.transaction.queue_size** key.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo! Thingsboard is up and running again! :)